# Загрузка библиотек из массива

Tags: c#, массивы, библиотеки

Есть некая программа для которой пользователи пишут расширения (библиотеки) и в каждой библиотеки стартовым методом является функция "Start()" с одинаковыми параметрами. Так вот вопрос, как можно подгрузить библиотеки из массива и вызвать их стартовый метод, если это возможно?

Comment: Для этого есть фреймворки, например, [MEF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Но на базовом уровне они все работают так, как описал @Donil.

Если ваше приложение сложное, возможно, имеет смысл посмотреть в сторону фреймворков.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Конечно возможно!

```
// Получаем все dll
FileInfo[] files = new DirectoryInfo("Директория с нашими плагинами").GetFiles("*.dll");
foreach (FileInfo fi in files)
{
    // Получаем assemly из файла
    var assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(fi.FullName);
    // Ищем нужный тип
    foreach (Type type in assembly.GetTypes())
    {
        ...

        // Нашли => Создаем экземпляр. Вместо многоточия идут параметры конструктора
        return Activator.CreateInstance(type, ...);
    }
}
```

Обычно, когда подобное реализуют, то описывают интерфейс, а в библиотеках описывают классы, которые его реализуют. В Вашем случае он будет выглядеть например так:

```
public interace IMyInterface
{
    void Start(...);
}
```

И тогда можно перебрать в библиотеке классы, реализующие его:

```
// Ищем нужный тип
foreach (Type type in assembly.GetTypes())
{
   // Проверяем является реализует ли тип type наш интерфейс
   if (!typeof (IMyInterface).IsAssignableFrom(type))
      continue;
   ...

   // Нашли => Создаем экземпляр. Вместо многоточия идут параметры конструктора
   return Activator.CreateInstance(type, ...);
}
```

Comment: В качестве оптимизации: можно сначала грузить сборку при помощи [`ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.reflectiononlyloadfrom.aspx), и только если нужный тип найден, грузить ещё раз по-настоящему через `LoadFile`. Таким образом вы избежите потерь в производительности на случай когда в сборке нет плагина.

Comment: @VladD, не знал о такой возможности. Спасибо за наводку!