# Загрузка dll не из корневого каталога

Tags: c#, .net, dll, assembly, appdomain

Я пишу консольную программку на C#, которая загружает из определённой папки dll-файлы. В каждом из dll есть класс, который реализует интерфейс IPlugin, и наследуется от MarshalByRefObject.

**Необходимо учесть 3 нюанса:**

1. Необходимо загружать в разные
   AppDomain
2. Файлы сборки лежат не в корневой
   папке где exe, а в отдельной, для
   плагинов(Plugins\plugins1\Plugins1.dll
   и Plugins\Plugins2\Plugins2.dll)
3. Не известно зарание структура dll.
   Т.е. нельзя хардкодить неймспейс и
   класс, как показано ниже:

   ```
   var plugin =
       (IPlugin)domain.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap(pathToDll, "PluginNamespace.Plugin1");
   ```

Пробовал загружать через метод `Load`:

```
var domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("NewDomain");
var buffer = File.ReadAllBytes(file);
var assembly = domain.Load(buffer);
```

Так работает только для сборок, которые лежат на одном уровне с ехе (не выполняется второе условие). Для dll внутри каталогов вылетает ошибка Could not load file or assembly... Прочитал где-то, что можно использовать `CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap` - с ним работает, но в него нужно передавать неймспейс и класс из сборки, а я его не знаю (3 условие). Знаю только что он реализует интерфейс `IPlugin`.

Помогите, пожалуйста, подскажите можно ли вообще при таких условиях загрузить сборки? Если можно, то как?

Comment: Ну вы даёте: `ReadAllBytes`. А потом будут говорить, что .NET тормозит. `Assembly.Load` умеет и из файла грузить вообще-то.

Такой вопрос недавно [был](/questions/323379/), там и код есть.

Comment: Внимательней вопрос читайте. Я понимаю что Assembly.Load умеет  грузить только из текущего домена. Первый пункт в условии.

Comment: Читал, читал. А что мешает выполнить `Assembly.Load` в нужном домене?

Создаёте процедуру, которая пробегается reflection'ом по assembly, ищет там нужные типы в соответствии с вашей логикой и запускает их на выполнение, и выполняете эту самую процедуру в другом домене. Всё вроде бы.

Comment: Он загружает всегда в текущий домен.

Comment: @vldl: Ну блин, читайте же что я пишу. Сделайте так, чтобы для него текущим доменом стал новый домен. Выполните этот код в другом домене. Создайте другой домен и выполните в нём `Assembly.Load`, а не в текущем.

Comment: При вызове в другом домене, он будет загружать сборку всё равно в текущий. Я пробовал с самого начала сделать с Assembly.Load, всё хорошо работало, но в только в текущем домене... Перерыл весь инет, пишут, что при загрузке в разные домены и если длл не в корне, то нужно использовать CreateInstanceFrom... Только вот ему нужно неймспейс и класс сказать(

Comment: @vldl:

> При вызове в другом домене, он будет загружать сборку всё равно в текущий

Не может быть, вы где-то слажали. Код в студию!

Comment: Попробуйте

`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.PrivateBinPath = String.Format("{0};{0}\\Директория с плагинами", Environment.CurrentDirectory);`

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
public class DomainResident : MarshalByRefObject
{
    public void LoadPluginFrom(string path)
    {
        // тут код из http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/323396
        // с Assembly.Load
    }
}

// ...
// не забудьте try/catch вокруг
var domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain(invent_some_NEW_name_here);

var resident = (DomainResident)domain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(
            typeof(DomainResident).Assembly.FullName,
            typeof(DomainResident).FullName);

resident.LoadPluginFrom(path);
```

Comment: Спасибо! Сейчас попробую. Правда, вроде, так пытался уже)

Comment: Поставьте в начало `LoadPluginFrom` 

    Console.WriteLine("Loading plugin in domain {0}",
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName);

На всякий пожарный.

Comment: ошибка на var resident = (DomainResident)domain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(
            typeof(DomainResident).Assembly.FullName,
            typeof(DomainResident).FullName);
Could not load file or assembly 'MainApp, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies.

Comment: @vldl: Хм. А вы из-под Visual Studio запускаете?

Comment: да на студии 2010

Comment: @vldl: У меня вот такое нормально работает: <http://pastebin.com/gjUkGZaf>. Попробуйте у себя. (У меня правда студия 2012.)

---
Кроме того, приведите полный дамп исключения. Всё, что имеет значение. FusionLog, например.

---
Ещё можно попробовать выгрузить `DomainResident` в отдельную сборку. Как описано [здесь](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173139%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). Только не в .exe, а в .dll, и пользуйтесь тем же `CreateInstanceAndUnwrap`, только указывайте ту сборку и то имя объекта.

Comment: спасибо, попробую

Comment: @vldl: отпишитесь о результатах. Тут лимит на количество комментариев, так что удаляйте старые.